# How do I stop a stopwatch at a certain amount of time?

Tags: c#, stopwatch

I am making a words per minute program (for class) and from what I've been researching, this *should* work. Basically, if the timer hits 10 seconds, I want the stopwatch to stop (though this is not necessary) and stop the user from typing anymore. How would I achieve this?

```
public void Timer30()
    {
        double userCharcount = 0;
        string userType;
        int timeInSeconds = 10;


        //new instance of stopwatch
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch( );

        //call level 1 words from wordbank
        Console.WriteLine(WordBank.LevelOneWords);
        stopWatch.Start( );

        //**this doesn't seem to work**
        if ( stopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds >= timeInSeconds )
        { Console.WriteLine("Time's up! Nice work.");
            stopWatch.Stop( );
            Console.ReadKey(); 
        }

        userType = Console.ReadLine( );
        stopWatch.Stop( );


        //capture number of characters user types to calculate WPM
        userCharcount = userType.Length;

        // Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

        // Format and display the TimeSpan value.
        string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}" ,
            ts.Hours , ts.Minutes , ts.Seconds ,
            ts.Milliseconds / 10);
        Console.WriteLine("\nNice job! You finished in " + elapsedTime + "!");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        //CalculateWPMEasy(userCharCount);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's go through what your code does:

1. `Console.WriteLine(WordBank.LevelOneWords);`. Ok, you print some words on the console. This statement finishes normally and execution advances to the next statement.
2. `stopWatch.Start( );`. Ok, you start the stopwatch. Time starts ticking. Execution advances to the next statement.
3. `if ( stopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds >= timeInSeconds )`. Ok, this executes *right after* you started the stopwatch... a few nanoseconds after, maybe? If `timeInSeconds` is anything higher than 0, `stopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds >= timeInSeconds` will be false.
4. Execution goes on...

How and when did you expect that seconds would go by between steps 2 and 3?

So, how do you fix this? Well the easy way, is to let the user type the words, no matter how slow he might be: `userType = Console.ReadLine( );`. *Only then* check the elapsed time and if its greater than `timeInSeconds` inform the user he was too slow.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `Console.ReadLine()` in that case, as that doesn't return control to your program until the user has hit Enter.  Try using `Console.ReadKey()` in a loop, where you check that the timeout hasn't expired.